# How to quickly deploy React / Redux app as a sample?

Tags: reactjs, redux

It seems one way is to deploy the React app to Heroku, but is there a simple way to deploy to our own website or to GitHub page feature so that you can see the page off from GitHub? (just as a sample, not for production)

---

Details:

It seems that one possible way may be to use

```
wget -r --no-parent http://localhost:8080 -P sample -nH
cp -rf images any_needed_folder sample
```

and now you can `git add sample` and `git commit` and push to github and turn on the GitHub page for your repo and be able to see your React app inside of `sample`.

You also need to change the paths in the `index.html`, from `/bundle.js` to `bundle.js`, etc, because you need relative path instead of going to the root of your website.

(I used `wget` to recursively download `index.html`, `bundle.js`, and `style/` (the CSS files) because `bundle.js` cannot be found in the whole directory on the local hard drive. I used `wget` because `curl` doesn't seem to be able to download recursively)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found that the latest React, it will tell you to use

```
create-react-app hello-world
```

to create the app, and then there is an official

```
npm run build
```

to build it to host it as a Gthub page, or on your own website.

Answer (score 0):

If wget is doing what you want, cool, use that.

For the actual deploying, I recommend using [gh-pages on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages). It handles creating an orphan branch and copying your output files into it, and then pushing all in one command.

Install it:

```
npm install --save-dev
```

And in an npm script:

```
gh-pages -d sample
```

Comment: so it is to use an orphan branch instead of "messing up" the master branch, and use that orphan branch as the GitHub page?

Comment: Mostly it makes it easier to publish to that branch since you don't need to switch branches and merge and have all of your source files in the gh-pages branch.